# Reasonable SSL handshake timeout (is user interaction feasible?)

Tags: java, ssl, https, x509, wildfly

I'm writing some code that will connect over https to a JBoss/Wildlfy server. Under certain circumstances, the server may require a client certificate on the SSL connection, in which case I will need to prompt the user for it (in a GUI)

Getting this working involves implementing the [X509KeyManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509KeyManager.html) interface, which one supplies to the low-level client code, and the methods on it will be called if the SSL client receives a request for a certificate from the server.

This is all well and good but I assume that if I try and prompt the user for a certificate within the X509KeyManager implementation then I suspect a reasonable amount of time to allow the user to choose a certificate in a UI far exceeds how long one can keep a server waiting during the handshake without it timing out.

The alternative is to bail out at this point, prompt the user to supply a certificate, and then retry connecting - with the X509KeyManager able to respond more or less instantaneously with the pre-chosen certificate. Obviously that means connecting to the server twice (well, 1.5 times), with increased latency.

Does anyone know whether user interaction is feasible? I presume web browsers have the same problem when a client certificate is requested/required, and I suspect they just retry the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The increased latency when reconnecting is far below the time to ask the user for the certificate, let it decide to choose the right one etc. On the other hand you tie up resources at the server if you just hang around connected, waiting for the user to choose a certificate. So I think the best option is to reconnect after the user has chosen the certificate.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I assumed... do you happen to know what sort of ballpark figure a server would be configured with for this? One of the reasons for asking the question was because I couldn't find an obvious answer anywhere and I thought it would be useful to have in an answer. I assume seconds but not tens and tens of seconds, since this would tie up resources and make denial attacks easier, and also because one doesn't want a user to be kept around waiting for ages before being told there is a problem.

Comment: I don't think there is a special timeout in the server for incomplete SSL handshake, but instead some kind of inactivity timeout on the socket. This might be long for servers with light load, but for servers with heavy load it is usually shorter.

Comment: *"I don't think there is a special timeout in the server"* - I believe Heartbleeds (err, beats) can be used to keep the connection alive. I'm not sure how to send one from application/user land, though.